# How to open Bootstrap Modal 3 seconds after click

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I need to click a button, and then it waits for 3 seconds, and then the modal opens.

Is it possible? If possible, give me the JavaScript code. I try the code below, but it automatically opens my modal after 3 seconds. I think the modal should be open only when I click the button, and then it holds and waits for 3 seconds, and then pop up the modal.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#basicModal").modal();
}, 3000);
```

Please help me.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" 
   data-toggle="modal" 
   data-target="#basicModal">Click to open Modal</a>
```

Comment: how ? plz send me code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will help you

Working solution using bootstrap modal

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

```
var timeoutId = 0;

function myFunction() {
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
$('#watch').on('click', function() {
  setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);
});
```

Comment: try both no success.. modal box open instantly when click

Comment: @AnanyaSharma In the code snippet it works I think, have you defined the function like `function myFunction(){
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
}`, the line `$("#basicModal").modal();` is only for initializing the modal I think, please define this line at the top of the script tag? if you can replicate the issue in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), I can look into it!

Comment: @AnanyaSharma Also, you can remove the attributes "data-toggle="modal" 
   data-target="#basicModal" since this will open the modal on click just like that! we are going to open the modal programmatically!

Comment: no dear it open #basicModal coz it have some content inside.

Comment: @AnanyaSharma Check my latest comment!

Comment: @AnanyaSharma Here is a JSFiddle with the solution working, please refer [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kai_Draord/5xhuLqb3/1/) for the solution

Comment: after remove data-toggle="modal" modal box not coming <button class="btn btn-success callback" id="watch" data-target="#basicModal">Download Now</button>

Comment: @AnanyaSharma Here is a JSFiddle with the solution working, please refer [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kai_Draord/5xhuLqb3/1/) for the solution

Comment: in JSFiddle after click nothing come out im try from safari+chrome

Comment: @AnanyaSharma, actually, I may have misunderstood your question wrong, do you want to just open the modal after three seconds on click of the link, or do you want to open the modal only if the button is clicked and hold for 3 seconds?

Comment: click wait for 3sec then popup modal box

Comment: @AnanyaSharma Do you want JQuery or javascript only solution?

Comment: jquery will be better

Comment: @AnanyaSharma Here is the solution [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Kai_Draord/7g7nmm5e/) Let me know if you face any issues implementing!